# libraries for live wallpapers development

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

This is the first time I am going to do a live wallpaper, I referred some tutorials across the web, but those tutorial were of very basic kind of live wallpapers. But when I tried searching for some advanced wallpaper tutorial, I was not able to find what I was looking. There are some great live wallpapers on Play Store and I was wondering how they were made. I mean using OpenGL or using some libraries. For e.g

[Live wallpaper 1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.FirefliesLiveWallpapersfree)

[Live wallpaper 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dualboot.apps.ocean)

Can anyone guide me as to what I need to learn in order to be able to create livewallpaper like one above?

Answer (score 1):

For creating such type of wallpaper you can use AndEngine and AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension Library

```
   https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

   https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension
```

Here you can change content of your wallpaper by touch Event easily